# Cumulative sum pandas DataFrame with indicator DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame (`df`) with information I'd like to sum based upon information in another pandas DataFrame (`dfIdx`) with the same columns and index.  In particular, if `df` takes the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[172770, 1442, 114581],[35464, 67062, 175285],[124399, 14294, 44104],[50608, 58802, 189253],[1000, 10000, 100000]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

and dfIdx of the following form:

```
dfIdx = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0],[0,0,1]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I want the result to be the cumulative sum of the rows in `df` preceding and including the rows in `dfIdx` with a value of `1`.  So the result should look like:

```
       A      B       C
0      0      0  114581
1      0      0       0
2      0  82798       0
3 383241  58802       0
4      0      0  508642
```

For extra credit, I'd like to be flexible with respect to how far back the cumulative sum includes contributions.  For example, if the window for the cumulative sum is `1`, then I'd only like to include at most one previous row, giving the result:

```
       A      B       C
0      0      0  114581
1      0      0       0
2      0  81356       0
3 175007  58802       0
4      0      0  289253
```

I realize the original example I gave did not provide all the examples of behavior that I wanted and, as a result, the suggested solution was incomplete.  I've augmented the data with another row to provide more diverse behavior.

Comment: If it helps, the solution proposed by @ScottBoston below seems to work if I modify his `df_group` to be `dfIdx.loc[list(reversed(dfIdx.index))].cumsum().loc[dfIdx.index,x.name]`.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT  To meet new requirements and expanded dataset

```
df_out = (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(dfIdx.loc[::-1,x.name].cumsum().replace(0,pd.np.nan).bfill())
                            .transform('cumsum')
                            .mul(dfIdx[x.name])))
```

Output:

```
        A      B       C
0       0      0  114581
1       0      0       0
2       0  82798       0
3  383241  58802       0
4       0      0  508642
```

Update for extra credit:

```
n=1 #for summing 1 pervious value
df_out = (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(dfIdx.loc[::-1,x.name].cumsum().replace(0,pd.np.nan).bfill())
                              .rolling(n+1,min_periods=1).sum().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
                              .mul(dfIdx[x.name])))
```

Output:

```
          A        B         C
0       0.0      0.0  114581.0
1       0.0      0.0       0.0
2       0.0  81356.0       0.0
3  175007.0  58802.0       0.0
4       0.0      0.0  289253.0
```

**Note:**  You were so close with  your observation using `reversed`.  I am doing the same thing.  It is all about how you group that dfIdx.

---

Let's try:

```
df_out = (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(dfIdx[x.name].cumsum().replace(0,pd.np.nan).bfill())
                            .transform('cumsum')
                            .mul(dfIdx[x.name])))
```

Output:

```
        A      B       C
0       0      0  114581
1       0      0       0
2       0  82798       0
3  383241  58802       0
```

And for "extra credit", where n=1, we use a rolling period of 2:

```
n=1 #for summing 1 pervious value
df_out = (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(dfIdx[x.name].cumsum().replace(0,pd.np.nan).bfill())
                              .rolling(n+1,min_periods=1).sum().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
                              .mul(dfIdx[x.name])))
```

Output:

```
          A        B         C
0       0.0      0.0  114581.0
1       0.0      0.0       0.0
2       0.0  81356.0       0.0
3  175007.0  58802.0       0.0
```

## How?

*Step 1 get the grouping in dfIdx:*

```
df_group = dfIdx.cumsum()\
     .replace(0,pd.np.nan)\
     .bfill()

     A    B  C
0  1.0  1.0  1
1  1.0  1.0  1
2  1.0  1.0  1
3  1.0  2.0  1
```

Step 2 Use that grouping to do 'transform' or 'rolling' on df.

```
df_out = df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(df_group)                              
  .rolling(n+1,min_periods=1)
  .sum()
  .reset_index(level=0,drop=True))

          A        B         C
0  172770.0   1442.0  114581.0
1  208234.0  68504.0  289866.0
2  159863.0  81356.0  219389.0
3  175007.0  58802.0  233357.0
```

*Step 3 Let's mask or replace those values aligned with 0 in dfIdx, we can use multiple*

df_out.mul(dfIdx)

```
          A        B         C
0       0.0      0.0  114581.0
1       0.0      0.0       0.0
2       0.0  81356.0       0.0
3  175007.0  58802.0       0.0
```